# debugging core text crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following stack trace and can't seem to figure out why coretext is crashing out:

[image]

```
-(CGSize)sizeConstrainedToSize:(CGSize)maxSize fitRange:(NSRange*)fitRange {
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString
                                                ((CFAttributedStringRef)self);
    CFRange fitCFRange = CFRangeMake(0,0);
    CGSize sz = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints
                      (framesetter,CFRangeMake(0,0),NULL,maxSize,&fitCFRange);
    if (framesetter) CFRelease(framesetter);
    if (fitRange) *fitRange = NSMakeRange(fitCFRange.location, fitCFRange.length);
    // take 1pt of margin for security
    return CGSizeMake( floorf(sz.width+1) , floorf(sz.height+1) ); 
}
```

Comment: Did you notice the double pointer? `*fitRange`

Comment: I think that is fine.. this works for some cases but not all cases

Comment: It looks to me like you're overreleasing a block in the log as well... Do you use GCD for this?

Comment: The screenshot cuts off the actual nature of the crash. I suspect something corrupt about the attributed string. Perhaps an attribute which is an object and that's been over-released and deallocated, so it's a dangling pointer.

Comment: Post the code that actually creates the attributed string to which you're sending the `sizeConstrainedToSize:fitRange:` message.

Comment: Are you setting a font in your attributed string?  Is it a `CTFont`?  The `CTFont` type is **not** the same as either `CGFont` or `UIFont`.  You must only use `CTFont` in an attributed string that you pass to Core Text on iOS.

Comment: @robmayoff it is a UIFont actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for the `kCTFontAttributeName` must be a `CTFontRef`, not a `UIFont` pointer.  There is no public function that converts a `UIFont` to `CTFontRef`, so you will need to create it using [`CTFontCreateWithName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Carbon/Reference/CTFontRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFontCreateWithName), perhaps like this:

```
UIFont *uiFont = ...;
CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)uiFont.fontName, uiFont.pointSize, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack trace, it looks like you are getting a crash from invoking CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString() from a secondary thread. See [CoreText crashes when run in multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642721/coretext-crashes-when-run-in-multiple-threads) and also the Apple docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_Framework_Ref/_index.html) that state the typesetter related APIs are not thread safe.